# How to get numbers from this type of string in C

Tags: c, string, integer, strtok, atoi

```
1 13 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12; 2 15 14 0
```

How can I get numbers from this string in ANSI C?

I tried to separate it with strtok() :

```
char *vstup = argv[1];
char delims[] = ";";
char *result = NULL;
result = strtok( vstup, delims );  

while( result != NULL ) {
    printf( "result is \"%s\"\n", result );
    result = strtok( NULL, delims );
}
```

and I got this:

```
result is "1 13 3 4"  
result is " 5 6 7 8"  
result is " 9 10 11 12"  
result is " 2 15 14 0"
```

Now I don't know how to get numbers in integers and save them to two-dimensional field (matrix). I need something like this:

```
field[1][1] = 1
.
.
.
etc.
```

I'm wondering about atoi(), but I'm not sure, if it would recognize for example "13" as one number..

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment.

Comment: how is the program set up? and how do you call it? give some more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use even space as delimiter. For example in ur case this code put the numbers in 2d array of size 4x4

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
char a[] = "1 13 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12; 2 15 14 0";
int i=0 ,j=0 , x;
int array[4][4];
char *temp;
temp = strtok(a," ;");
do
{
    array[i][j] = atoi(temp);
    if(j == 4)
    {
        i++;
        j = 0;
    }
    j++;
}while(temp = strtok(NULL," ;"));

for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<4 ;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the exact same thing you did for stripping up to the ';' but instead also use ' ' for spaces. Place this result into an array and you can use atoi or whatever you want on the entire array. If you want to put it into a 2-d array you can split the string up to the ';' and then within that loop split each integer into whatever part of the array you want to. Won't write the code as it looks like homework.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use sscanf:

```
char* input = ...;
while(*input) {
    input += ';' == *input;
    int a, b, c, d, n = -1;
    sscanf(input, "%d %d %d %d%n", &a, &b, &c, &d, &n);
    if(n < 0)
        // parsing error
    // parsed successfully into a, b, c, d
    input += n;
}
```

Note, that the input string is left unchanged here.